# How to Periodically Send a HTTP Status Code 102 Processing Response through Grizzly

Tags: java, http, asynchronous, grizzly

I have a Java application which runs on top of Grizzly web server.  I already call `Response.suspend()` and run the request in a background thread.  This much works great.  Here's some example code of this.

```
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Response;

class Handler extends org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler
{
   @Override
   public void service(Request request, Response response)
   {
       response.suspend();
       // Execute the request in a background thread
   }

   private static void execute(Request request, Response response)
   {
      // Process the request

      response.setStatus(200);
      // Populate the response headers and body
      response.resume();
   }
}
```

For one kind of request, the processing could take a while.  I would like to send HTTP status code `102 Processing` periodically back to the client so that the client doesn't time out.  How do I do this?  I realize I might have to run a periodic scheduled task to send the `102 Processing`.  This isn't a problem.  How do I interact with the `Response` object?

I tried the following while the request is being processed.  This sends back the 102 HTTP status code to the client.  However, when the actual response is ready to send to the client, an `IllegalStateException` is thrown because `Response.isCommitted()` is true.

```
response.setStatus(102, "Processing");

response.
   getOutputBuffer().
   acknowledge();
```